# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class androidx.test.espresso.base.ThreadPoolExecutorExtractor$2

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, robolectric

Getting following error whenever trying to run my test-cases. (from "test" package not from "androidTest"), while using Robolectric.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced above issue while using espresso with robolectric. Also above issue is coming due testing via Robolectric & Espresso.

To resolve the issue, make sure to cross check your Robolectric artifact-version to stable one. https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric

I have accidentally used version as "4.+", which took the alpha version and produced the above logs. Now have updated to "4.5.1" which resolved the above issue.